# sql server insert data file_get_contents php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, blob

i have a php code that inserts into a mysql database data and a blob (img and/or pdf).

i have to mirgate database to sql server, when i try to execute the code to insert data into a sql server table, sql server shows me this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]No se permite la conversion implicita del tipo de datos nvarchar(max) a varbinary(max). Utilice la funcion CONVERT para ejecutar esta consulta.
```

the code is the following:

```
$destino = addslashes( file_get_contents( $value['tmp_name'] ) );

                $tmpName = $value['tmp_name'];

                // Read the file

                $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

                $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

                $destino = ($data);

                fclose($fp);

                $tamano = $value['size'];

                $tipo   = $value['type'];
                $name   = $value['name];

$sql="INSERT INTO documentacion 
        ( nombre, archivo,extension ) 
        VALUES 
        ( :nombre, :archivo, :extension)";


$valores = array(
    ':nombre'       =>$name,
    ':archivo'      =>utf8_encode( $destino ),
    ':extension'    =>$tipo,
);

try{

    $ejec=$bd->ejecuta($sql,$valores);  
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo 'Error BD al insertar documentacion: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
return $ejec[0];
```

anybody can tell me how i have to do to convert nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit conversion https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx .

Example

```
declare @t table (val varbinary(max));

declare @s varchar(max) = 'Some text';

insert @t(val) values(cast(@s as varbinary(max)));

select cast(val as varchar(max))
from @t;
```

In your code I think it should be

```
VALUES 
   ( :nombre, cast(:archivo as varbinary(max)), :extension)
```

Comment: Thanks inserts it fine, but how can i show the blob in a website page. In Mysql i have the following: `header("Content-type: {$doc->extension}");

    echo ( $doc->archivo );` ($doc->archivo) is the value received in sql select query. I have to change something of my code to runs with Sql server ? thanks again

Comment: You can convert `varbinary` column to `varchar` with `select .. cast(archivo as varchar(max)) as archivo` and proceed with the conversion (if any) reverse to which you applied to initial file content before passing it as a parameter to `insert`.

Comment: the array values to the insert are `$valores = array(
    ':nombre'       =>$name,
    ':archivo'      =>utf8_encode( $destino ),
    ':extension'    =>$tipo,
);` and to proceed to conversion to show the img/pdf i would be `utf8_decode($doc->archivo)` . i not sure that i understand you well, i did this and the website page returns me a white page without img/pdf. i don't know what i'm doing wrong but in mysql worked fine. thanks for the responses